# How to delete a user in Lotus Notes Traveler if they have no devices

Tags: lotus-domino

I need to delete a user in Lotus Notes Traveler. I enter the command:

tell traveler delete

But the console tells me there is no device by that name,

I dot a tell traveler user user and I see the user has no device.

So how the heck can I delete the user?

Comment: Better go to servervault, this is not a developer question. What does "tell traveler show username" say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tell traveler delete "DEVICEID"  (see for them in ex. Traveler.nsf) "USERNAME" (CANONICAL)

Syntax used without -->" ;)

Comment: Thanks Pete! Appreciate it.